# moment.js – get next existing day of array

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an array filled with different days:

```
let days = ["2018-09-02", "2018-10-06", "2018-10-12", "2018-10-24", "2018-11-02", "2018-11-04"];
```

How can I detect which of those days is the closest day in the future from today?

My current state can detect, if tomorrow is part of the array but I don't know how to get the closest day in the future when tomorrow doesn't exist.

```
let nextDay = day.add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  if (day[i] === nextDay) {
    // next day is part of the array
    console.log(nextDay);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Just an observation you can use `days.includes(nextDay)` instead of the forloop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Are the dates in the array always sorted like in your example or can they be randomized?

Comment: You can try the fromNow method of moment https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Comment: @HelgeFox the array can be randomized

Comment: `const today = moment(), next = days.slice().sort().find(date => today.isBefore(date));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility would be to subtract each date from the current date and see which date is the least positive days away.

Example:

```js
let days = ["2018-09-02", "2018-10-06", "2018-10-12", "2018-10-30", "2018-11-02", "2018-11-04", "2019-01-01"];
let curDay = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
let closestDay;
let closestDiff;
for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  let diff = moment(days[i]).diff(curDay, 'days'); 
  if(diff > 0){
    if(closestDiff === undefined) {
      closestDay = days[i];
      closestDiff = diff;
    } else if(diff < closestDiff) {
      closestDay = days[i];
      closestDiff = diff;
    }
  }
}
if(closestDay === undefined) closestDay = "no days found in the future";
document.getElementById("closest-future").innerHTML = closestDay;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="moment.js@2.14.1" data-semver="2.14.1" src="https://npmcdn.com/moment@2.14.1"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>Shortest date in the future is: <span id='closest-future'></span></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array is sorted, you can do the following:

```js
let days = ["2018-09-02", "2018-10-06", "2018-10-12", "2018-10-24", "2018-11-02", "2018-11-04"];
let today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(days.find(d => d > today));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.19.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! How would I get the closest day in the past? days.find(d => d < today) seems to get the first index of the array

Comment: @iamrobin. Using `days.reverse().find(d => d < today)` would be a possibility, or using `reduce`.